# How to create multiple copies of stacks?

Tags: c++

I need to create a combination of two stacks taking elements from them in turns one by one, so I've decided to create a copy of each stack to restore them later on (since they have to remain) and another stack that would be the combination of the two.

Here's the code I wrote:

```
void solution(stack_of_numbers*& top1, stack_of_numbers*& top2, stack_of_numbers*& top_combined)
{
    stack_of_numbers* clipboard_stack1 = NULL;
    stack_of_numbers* clipboard_stack2 = NULL;
    stack_of_numbers clipboard_number;

    while (top1 || top2)
    {
        if (top1)
        {
            clipboard_number.num = pop_back(top1);
            clipboard_stack1 = push_back(clipboard_stack1, clipboard_number);
            top_combined = push_back(top_combined, clipboard_number);
        }
        if (top2)
        {
            clipboard_number.num = pop_back(top2);
            clipboard_stack2 = push_back(clipboard_stack2, clipboard_number);
            top_combined = push_back(top_combined, clipboard_number);
        }
    }

    move_element(clipboard_stack1, top1);
    move_element(clipboard_stack2, top2);
```

Functions and the struct that I'm running:

```
struct stack_of_numbers
{
    int num;
    struct stack_of_numbers* next;
};

struct stack_of_numbers* push_back(stack_of_numbers* top, stack_of_numbers number)
{
    stack_of_numbers* clipboard_number = new stack_of_numbers;
    (*clipboard_number).num = number.num;
    (*clipboard_number).next = top;
    return clipboard_number;
}

int pop_back(stack_of_numbers*& top)
{
    stack_of_numbers* clipboard_number = top;
    int num = (*clipboard_number).num;
    top = (*clipboard_number).next;
    delete clipboard_number;
    return num;
}

void move_element(stack_of_numbers*& top1, stack_of_numbers*& top2)
{
    stack_of_numbers* clipboard_number;
    clipboard_number = top1;
    top1 = (*top1).next;
    (*clipboard_number).next = top2;
    top2 = clipboard_number;
}
```

However, when the program is executed, stacks are not copied and restored as they should be.
Here are the original stacks:

```
Stack 1:
0
8
7
0
5
3
1
-----------------------------------
Stack 2:
-10
-9
-6
-4
-2
```

And here are the stacks after I attempt to copy and combine them:

```
Stack 1:
1
-----------------------------------
Stack 2:
-2
-----------------------------------
Combined stack:
1
3
-2
5
-4
0
-6
7
-9
8
-10
0
```

Only the last elements of each stack left, whereas they should remain as they were at the beginning. I think the problem is in the push_back() function, but I can't tell where exactly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Usually in stacks there is declared member function push instead of push_back. Also it is totally unclear why the second parameter of the function has the  stack type.

Comment: Can't use built-in functions (education huh). As for the function parameter, replacing it with an integer doesn't help, I've tried, although it is indeed unnecessary.

Comment: Easiest thing would be to pass `top1` and `top2` as copy in `solution`. As you are making copy inside anyways. This way you do not have to do anything after you form new stack.

Comment: Make a stack class to manage the stack. It should make your life easier. Make it observe the [Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) and your problem goes away.

Comment: @Lurtsh  Show how the combined stack should look.

Comment: Original stacks:
`
Stack 1:
8
7
5
3
1
-----------------------------------
Stack 2:
0
-10
-9
-6
0
-4
-2
`
Here's what I got:
`
Stack 1:
8
-----------------------------------
Stack 2:
0
-----------------------------------
Combined stack:
-2
-4
0
1
-6
3
-9
5
-10
7
0
8
`
So now the first elements are left. For some reason it doesn't get copied into both new and combined stack

Comment: Try not to pass references to pointers. C++ tries to encourage references above all else, pointers *when necessary*. References to pointers is just confused. Also use `nullptr` in preference to `NULL`.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow it's in the first example. that's a correct combined stack, but the original ones are not

Comment: @user4581301 i wish I could use classes, but I'm not allowed to because education huh

Comment: First order of business is to pass the class, but... See if you can get away with using another `struct`. In C++ structs and classes are pretty much the same. The only difference you're ever likely to notice is `class` defaults to `private` member and base class access and `struct` defaults to `public`. You can put member functions, constructors, operator overloads, and all the rest of the goodies into a `struct`.

Comment: @user4581301 Ik what a struct in C++ is, but I'm not allowed to use OOP here, that's the problem

Comment: Huh looks like I've solved it accidentally. In any case, thanks everyone for useful insight regarding the quality and structure of my code:)